# A word for "retainedness"

Tags: single-word-requests

When one says "this is too sticky" or "this isn't sticky at all" one is talking about an object's *stickiness*. Is there a word to say the same about something's possibility (or lack thereof) of being *retained*?

Comment: Which meaning of 'retain' are you thinking of? Possession, servicemen, memory, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"***[Retainability](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retain)***".

> **retainability**
> Selectees, none over age 39, had to be physically fit, mentally awake and morally straight, with saber-sharp military bearing and at least 15 months ***retainability***.

Comment: Couldn't upvote due to low reputation, but marked as accepted! Many thanks!

Comment: @Rathony - Ah thanks - didn't know that!  Guess I should hang around on meta more often!